# The sum (or difference) of two irrational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

So far I that for any irrational number without a real part (that $-n=\overline{n}$) plus/minus any irrational number with the same restrictions equals another irrational number. However, I want to know if there is a concrete rule that states what the properties of a sum/difference made up of irrational numbers. My intuition says that two irrational numbers will only add up to a rational number if their irrational parts are opposites (for instance $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$), but I'm not really sure.

Thank you!

MAJOR EDIT: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention something very important. The irrational numbers in this problem are all in the form $a+\sqrt{b}$ where a and b are both positive integers and $\sqrt{b}$ is irrational.

Comment: How do you define the irrational part of a real number?

Comment: Isn't any nonzero complex number with no real part irrational? The rationals are a subset of the reals.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not very good at this type of math, but here's what I was trying to say: If we have an irrational number (like $2+\sqrt{2}$, then in my (possibly convoluted and incorrect reasoning), the 2 would be the rational part and the $\sqrt{2}$ would be the irrational part.

Comment: But why wouldn't you have $3$ be the rational part, and $\sqrt 2 - 1$ the irrational part? Or $4$ and $\sqrt 2 - 2$, or so on?

Comment: In your examples, I think that the rational part is the sum of all the rational parts. The purpose for this weird terminology is that so we can get rid of the irrational stuff and be left with the rational. Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach?

Comment: There is no sum of all the rational parts: if $x$ is irrational and $q$ is rational then $x=q+(x-q)$. $q$ can be as big as I want, so I can't add them up. In short, there is no way to "get rid of the irrational stuff".

Comment: @just1question the problem T. Bongers points out is much worse than you think. For one thing, not all irrational numbers are root things, or could have anything like an intuitive idea of what you mean by "rational part." The only reasonable definition I can think of that fits in with general theory would be if they were in a common algebraic field and choosing an integral basis with $\text{span}\{1\}$ as the "rational" part, and even that's stretching it, especially with transcendence issues.

Comment: Thanks Ian! So, how do you think I should go about this problem of imposing restrictions on irrational numbers so that they add (or subtract) to a rational number?

Comment: @just1question In particular, it's unlikely you will come up with **any** sensible definition which will give you anything useful to talk about, let alone prove things about. Can you add context to why you're trying to figure something like this out? If it's for a class, they probably just want you to note that you can add irrationals to get a rational. If it's personal, I'd say giving up is the right choice here. How would one, for example, define the "rational part" of

$$\sum_n 10^{-n!}$$

Comment: **I'm sorry guys, I forgot to add something very important to the problem. Please see the edit. I hope this clears things up. :)**

Comment: With your new restriction, your intuition is more or less correct. A more concrete way to say this is the observation that the set of square-free radicals $\{1,\ \sqrt{2},\ \sqrt{3},\ \cdots \}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: A little more context would be appreciated. This set of numbers isn't even closed under simple addition: $(1+\sqrt{2}) + (1+\sqrt{3}) \neq a+\sqrt{b}$ for any choice of integers $a,b$.

Comment: @MPW, please see my earlier definition. I'm saying that the square root parts must be "opposites" of each other, so in your example, it would be something like $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$. Or am I missing something? All I want to know is what restrictions do we need to have in order for the sum/difference to be rational.

Comment: Thank you, @EuYu, but do you have any ideas on how to rigorously prove this? Would proving that the sum of two irrational square roots is irrational and working from there work?

Comment: @just1question This is a pretty well known fact. For example, this [paper](http://www.thehcmr.org/issue2_1/mfp.pdf) has several proofs. The paper proves the general result, but it wouldn't be too difficult to prove this in the case of a small number of radicals (since it seems you are primarily interested in the case of $a+\sqrt{b}$.